# Finding a function with unchanged minima under self composition

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

I need to find a smooth continous function $f$ such that for any strictly positive real numbers $A,B,C$ it holds that

1. $f(A,B)>0$
2. $f(A,B)<f(B,A)$ when $A<B$
3. $f(A,B)<f(A+s,B)$ and $f(A,B)<f(A,B+s)$ where $s>0$ and $0<A<B$
4. $f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(D,E),F)$ where $[D,E,F]$ is a permutation of $[A,B,C]$ and $0<A<B<C$. Full list below

$f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(B,A),C)$

$f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(C,A),B)$

$f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(A,C),B)$

$f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(B,C),A)$

$f(f(A,B),C)<f(f(C,B),A)$

Answer (score 1):

**[NOTE]** following function was proposed before requirement 3 was introduced. 
Now it does not suffice to solve the full problem, but I leave it here for historical reasons and as a good point to start thinking.

Probably 
$$
f(x;y) = \frac{x+1}{y}
$$
may do the job.
For $0 < A < B < C$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(A;B)       = \frac{A+1}{B}  &<_1 \frac{B+1}{A} = f(B;A)\\
f(f(A;B); C) = \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} &<_2 \frac{B+1}{AC} + \frac{1}{C} = f(f(B; A); C)\\
f(f(A;B); C) = \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} &<_3 \frac{C+1}{AB} + \frac{1}{B} = f(f(C; A); B)\\
f(f(A;B); C) = \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} &<_4 \frac{A+1}{CB} + \frac{1}{B} = f(f(A; C); B)\\
f(f(A;B); C) = \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} &<_5 \frac{B+1}{AC} + \frac{1}{A} = f(f(B; C); A)\\
f(f(A;B); C) = \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} &<_6 \frac{C+1}{AB} + \frac{1}{A} = f(f(C; B); A)
\end{aligned}
$$

**Proof 1:**
$$
A < B \Rightarrow (A + 1/2)^2 < (B + 1/2)^2
\Rightarrow A^2 + A < B^2 + B
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{B} < \frac{B + 1}{A}
$$
**Proof 2:** use proof 1
$$
\frac{A + 1}{B} < \frac{B + 1}{A}
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{BC} < \frac{B + 1}{AC}
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} < \frac{B + 1}{AC} + \frac{1}{C}
$$
**Proof 3:** use proof 1 and change $B \rightarrow C$
$$
\frac{A + 1}{C} < \frac{C + 1}{A}
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{BC} < \frac{C + 1}{AB}
$$
Note that
$$
0 < B < C \Rightarrow \frac{1}{C} < \frac{1}{B}
$$
and add
$$
\frac{A + 1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} < \frac{C + 1}{AB} + \frac{1}{B}
$$
**Proof 4:**
$$
0 < B < C \Rightarrow \frac{1}{C} < \frac{1}{B}
\Rightarrow \frac{A+1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} < \frac{A+1}{CB} + \frac{1}{B}
$$
**Proof 5:** use proof 1
$$
\frac{A + 1}{B} < \frac{B + 1}{A}
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{BC} < \frac{B + 1}{AC}
$$
Note that
$$
0 < A < C \Rightarrow \frac{1}{C} < \frac{1}{A}
$$
and add
$$
\frac{A + 1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} < \frac{B + 1}{AC} + \frac{1}{A}
$$
**Proof 6:** use proof 1 and change $B \rightarrow C$
$$
\frac{A + 1}{C} < \frac{C + 1}{A}
\Rightarrow \frac{A + 1}{BC} < \frac{C + 1}{AB}
$$
Note that
$$
0 < A < C \Rightarrow \frac{1}{C} < \frac{1}{A}
$$
and add
$$
\frac{A + 1}{BC} + \frac{1}{C} < \frac{C + 1}{AB} + \frac{1}{A}
$$

Comment: Thank you, your soluton is correct but made me realize the I missed the fact that f(A,B) needs to be increasing as A,B increase so I edited the OP to relfect this